# Looking for AWS S3 redirect rule for images within indes.html/img.png

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

background: I have an issue that happened when I have integrated my static website with salesforce, it looks for the my index file in the s3 bucket address i gave it but it looks for its images in a location under index.html
something like:
bucketaddress.../index.html/img.png while the image is actually located in the same folder as the index.html file itself

I have seen that there are redirection rules within a bucket properties(in the "Edit static website hosting" section),
Is there some way to make every call to retrieve such image to look for it in the correct location?

I have tried the following syntax:

```
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "index.html/icon.png"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "icon.png"
        }
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "index.html/dragIcon.png"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "dragIcon.png"
        }
    }
]
```

but it doesnt work for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Replacing KeyPrefix may not be what you want to do there,
example should redirect index.html/icon.png -> icon.png/icon.png
and index.html/dragIcon.png ->dragIcon.png/dragIcon.png

If you change your Redirect to "ReplaceKeyWith": ....
instead of "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith":
it should work the way you expect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).